# sequence of goals on rviz for robot navigation

Tags: ros, navigation, rviz, amcl-pose, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi every one,

I want my TurtleBot robot to navigate on environment map autonomous. I found that it is using amcl, which allow to give a goal to the robot in rviz then robot will move to it, but this is not so great. I found that there is exploration I still try to run it.
:
now I want to know

1- If I can give the robot a sequence of goals instead of one goal on rviz to work as if it explore all the environment not just move to one place on it  ?!

2- If I can link each goal with specific action for example to do object recognition at specific point on the map ?!

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61628/sequence-of-goals-on-rviz-for-robot-navigation/) by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on 2013-04-26**:
something like one on this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w8LwjhR1ZgY

**Comment by [Muhammad Elmallah](https://answers.ros.org/users/28557/muhammad-elmallah/) on 2017-01-10**:
Could you do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You will have to implement a node with a state machine that describes such process.

You can store the sequence of goals in that node.  First the node would publish the first goal. Then, the node would need to read the position of the robot and wait to the robot is close enough to that first goal. If the goal is considered reached, then the node would publish a next goal position. This process would be repeated until the whole sequence is accomplished.

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2016-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Muhammad Elmallah](https://answers.ros.org/users/28557/muhammad-elmallah/) on 2017-01-10**:
Is there a tutorial for how to link the node with the navigation stack?